# Загрузить 2 видео одновременно

Tags: javascript, html5

```js
let myvid = document.getElementById('my-player');
let myvids = [
  "1.MOV",
  "2.MOV",
];
let activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  activeVideo = activeVideo++;

  myvid.src = myvids[1];

  const playPromise = myvid.play();
  if (playPromise !== null) {
    playPromise.catch(() => {
      myvid.play();
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<video id="my-player2" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" poster="second.mp4" data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="2.MOV" type=" video/mp4"/>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
        web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">
            supports HTML5 video
        </a>
    </p>
</video>
```

Есть 2 видео, которые я загружаю одно за другим. После того как 1 заканчивается, браузер в течение некоторого малого времени подгружает 2 видео и воспроизводит его. **Как заранее подгрузить 2 видео, чтобы не было "раздумий"?**

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать как и в случае с картинкой:
создаем через JS tag VIDEO, устанавливаем source с нужной ссылкой, video подгружается, а потом в нужный момент просто меняем source уже на подгруженное видео:

```js
const item = document.querySelector('#item');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const video = document.querySelector('#video');
const nextVideo = document.createElement("VIDEO");
nextVideo.setAttribute("src","https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4");


button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 video.setAttribute("src","https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4");
})
```

```html
<div id="item">
 <video id="video" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" controls></video>
</div>
<button>Click for next video</button>
```

Comment: Этот способ не подходит. Появляется быстрый "чёрный проскок", перед воспроизведением 2

Comment: Но видео при этом ведь подгружено, его страница все равно должна рендерить вне зависимости оно загрузилось или нет. Сделать какой-то pre-change: opacity, slide in ? PS и у меня нет никаких черных проскоков, видео заменяется моментально.

Comment: https://zhvladislav.github.io/player.html посмотрите по ссылочке :) 2 видео загружается после конца 1